# Break an array of saved list from droppable area

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a loop of droppable objects. I want to save and print list of objects for each row in the loop. I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/ny1n9gm0/) here with two rows. So what i want is two different lines of saved objects, for each row.
Here is code with loop:

```
            <label><?php for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
                        {
                            echo "<div class='proc'> <pre>";
                            echo "Process: ".$proc[$y]."      ";
                            echo "People required: ".$num[$y]."     ";  
                            echo "<span class='assigned' name='assigned[]' >People Assigned: </span><br /></pre>";  
                    ?>
                    <div class="procLeader">
                    <label>Leader:</label>
                        <div class="ui-widget-content">
                        <div class="procleader">
                            <ol>
                                <li class="placeholder" name="procleader[]" <?php if (isset($procleader)) echo 'value="'.$procleader.'"' ?>>Add Process Leader here</li>
                                <input type="hidden" name="procleader[]" class="hiddenListInput3" />
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="procChecker">
                    <label>Checker:</label>
                        <div class="ui-widget-content">
                        <div class="procchecker">
                            <ol>
                                <li class="placeholder" name="procchecker[]" <?php if (isset($procchecker)) echo 'value="'.$procchecker.'"' ?>>Add Process Checker here</li>
                                <input type="hidden" name="procchecker[]" class="hiddenListInput4" />
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prodStuff">
                    <label>Stuff:</label>
                        <div class="ui-widget-content">
                        <div class="prodstuff">
                            <ol>
                                <li class="placeholder" name="prodstuff[]" <?php if (isset($prodstuff)) echo 'value="'.$prodstuff.'"' ?>>Add Stuff here</li>
                                <input type="hidden" name="prodstuff[]" class="hiddenListInput5" />
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php       
                        echo "</div>";                      
                        }
                    ?>
            </label>
```